Euclidean Geometry Problem - Algebraic Approach
The following question was asked and closed:

For two points $A \neq B$ let
$C_r = \{X \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |X − A| = r|X − B|\}$ for $r > 0$.
For $r = 1$, $C_r$ is the perpendicular bisector of $l_{AB}$ . Prove that for $r \neq 1$, $C_r$ is a circle.

Solution is below, other approaches are appreciated.

FYI: For varying $r$, these $C_r$ form a family of Apollonian circles; specifically, the first ("blue") family defined in the Wikipedia entry.

Let us think of the problem in the following way. Given some arbitrary value $k$, the set $\{X\in \mathbb{R}^2:|X-A|=k\}$ gives a circle centered around $A$ of radius $k$. The set $\{X\in \mathbb{R}^2:k=r|X-B|\}$ gives a circle centered around $B$ with a radius of $k/r$. But the set $\{X\in \mathbb{R}^2:|X-A|=k=r|X-B|\}$ is the intersection of these two circles. To find the set $C_r$ then, we must vary over all possible $k$.
This gives us motivation for the following algebraic construction.
The equation for a circle of radius $k$ centered at point $(a,b)$ is
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=k^2.$$
Let $A$ have the coordinates $(a_x,a_y)$ and $B$ have the coordinates $(b_x,b_y)$. The equation of the two circles mentioned above are:
$$(x-a_x)^2+(y-a_y)^2=k^2$$
and,
$$(x-b_x)^2+(y-b_y)^2=\frac{k^2}{r^2}.$$
The second equation can be written as: $r^2(x-b_x)^2+r^2(y-b_y)^2=k^2$, then setting it equal to the first we get:
$$r^2(x-b_x)^2+r^2(y-b_y)^2=(x-a_x)^2+(y-a_y)^2.$$
Through some algebraic manipulations, it can be shown (given $r\neq1$) that this equation can be re-written as:
$$\left(x-\frac{r^2b_x-a_x}{r^2-1}\right)^2+\left(x-\frac{r^2b_y-a_y}{r^2-1}\right)^2=\left(\frac{r^2b_x-a_x}{r^2-1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{r^2b_y-a_y}{r^2-1}\right)^2-\frac{r^2b_x^2-a_x^2}{r^2-1}-\frac{r^2b_y^2-a_y^2}{r^2-1}$$
which is the equation of a circle.
Here is a demo to play around with in Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a6cc3un47j

These circles are known under the name Apollonian circles.
